# Palm Pre frameworks

Tags: javascript, jquery, yui, webos, palm-pre

I have some measure of web development experience (not my main skill, but I am pretty good with the basics)

What I'm sorely lacking is knowledge of and experience with modern JS frameworks (Prototype, jQuery, YUI, whatnot). I'd like to play with them (all eventually but need to start with one).

Here's the problem: I'm **very** interested in trying out my skills on Palm Pre eventually. To the extent that the main criteria for choosing which JS framework to learn first for me is this:

**Which mainstream modern JS framework is the most useful to learn if the main criteria is "knowing this will help me most to develop for Palm Pre"**?

I'm assuming it will be one of the 3 I mentioned: jQuery/YUI/Prototype, unless I'm missing some major well known JS/wevdev framework? I intend to try all those 3 eventually so their relative merits outside of helping on PalmPre are not majorly important.

Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The framework that Palm provides in the SDK is called Mojo.

Mojo is built on top of Prototype, therefore you will automatically have access to Prototype when you work on the Pre, and you will have to make use of it for various system calls.

Therefore, you are probably going to get the most benefit from learning Prototype.

That said, it is possible to add other js libraries like jQuery if you prefer to use those for your Pre apps.

Check out the webOSdev [API Reference](http://developer.palm.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=1654) for more information about the Mojo Framework.

Comment: Thanks - I'd up-vote you but short 4 points (this is my firts S.O. foray) :(

Comment: I've successfully completed an app with jQuery integration. You'll have to use noConflict, but apart from that it's pretty flexible. It definitely comes in handy with jQuery's superior handling of AJAX.