# How to use jquery in palm mojo?

Tags: jquery, webos, palm-pre, palm

How do I do to be able to use jquery in my palm mojo application?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545773/palm-pre-frameworks), especially the comments.

Edit in response to the comments:

I don't know about Palm development so I can't help you out in detail. Mojo however is based on Prototype. Prototype and JQuery crash because they have identical function names. That's where the noConflict plugin comes in. You can read up on it [here](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/07/jquerynoconflict-resolving-conflicts.html) and get it [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/jQuery.noConflict). That's about all I can tell you about it - maybe somebody else can take you through the process step by step.

Comment: I have tried and not succeeded. So I will need a example on how to do this.

Comment: Did you try using noConflict?

Comment: The thing is that I do not know what to do. noConflict does not say me much. I'm new to jquery. Have tried finding examples on the web but not found anything that helps me.

Comment: I have got a web page, using jquery, working fine in my web browser, and I'm trying to use the same code in my palm pre application, but do not know how to get it to work. I have downloaded jquery and included the script in my code. What else do I need to do?
A small example working on palm pre would be good. Tanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

1. Import Mojo
2. Import jQuery
3. Create a Script block that contains jQuery.noConflict();
4. Follow with your normal jQuery *except* using 'jQuery' instead of '$'

E.g., `jQuery('div#idOfSomething').hide();`